# Python: efficient way to match 2 different length arrays and find index in larger array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, matching

I have 2 arrays: `x` and `bigx`. They span the same range, but `bigx` has many more points.
e.g.

```
x = np.linspace(0,10,100)
bigx = np.linspace(0,10,1000)
```

I want to find the indices in `bigx` where `x` and `bigx` match to 2 significant figures. I need to do this extremely quickly as I need the indices for each step of an integral.

Using `numpy.where` is very slow:

```
index_bigx = [np.where(np.around(bigx,2) == i) for i in np.around(x,2)]
```

Using `numpy.in1d` is ~30x faster

```
index_bigx = np.where(np.in1d(np.around(bigx), np.around(x,2) == True)
```

I also tried using `zip` and `enumerate` as I know that's supposed be faster but it returns empty:

```
>>> index_bigx = [i for i,(v,myv) in enumerate(zip(np.around(bigx,2), np.around(x,2))) if myv == v]
>>> print index_bigx
[]
```

I think I must have muddled things here and I want to optimise it as much as possible. Any suggestions?

Comment: **`numpy.in1d`** looks most optimised way from the listed possibilities you have tried.

Comment: Yes, but it is still too slow for my purposes. I am hoping someone can suggests another efficient pythonic way to do it.

Comment: Are `x` and `bigx` always uniform (like they are in your example)? Are they always sorted?

Comment: Is it expected that the arrays will be evenly spaced, like they are in the example? Also, `around(0.0049, 2) != around(0.0051, 2)`; should those be considered matching?

Comment: Both arrays are always sorted. `bigx` is always evenly spaced (and it's fixed), `x` is not evenly spaced and it is a variable that changes - hence why I want this matching to be efficient as I have to do it multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `bigx` is always evenly spaced, it's quite straightforward to just directly compute the indices:

```
start = bigx[0]
step = bigx[1] - bigx[0]
indices = ((x - start)/step).round().astype(int)
```

Linear time, no searching necessary.

Comment: Smart approach this one!

Comment: Thanks! Simple and fast! And it eliminates the errors from np.around

Answer (score 1):

Since we are mapping `x` to `bigx` which has its elemments equidistant, you can use a binning operation with [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to simulate the index finding operation using its `'left'` option. Here's the implementation -

```
out = np.searchsorted(np.around(bigx,2), np.around(x,2),side='left')
```

**Runtime tests**

```
In [879]: import numpy as np
     ...: 
     ...: xlen = 10000
     ...: bigxlen = 70000
     ...: bigx = 100*np.linspace(0,1,bigxlen)
     ...: x = bigx[np.random.permutation(bigxlen)[:xlen]]
     ...: 

In [880]: %timeit np.where(np.in1d(np.around(bigx,2), np.around(x,2)))
     ...: %timeit np.searchsorted(np.around(bigx,2), np.around(x,2),side='left')
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 4.1 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.81 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the elements, this should work:

```
np.intersect1d(np.around(bigx,2), np.around(x,2))
```

If you want the indices, try this:

```
around_x = set(np.around(x,2))
index_bigx = [i for i,b in enumerate(np.around(bigx,2)) if b in around_x]
```

Note: these were not tested.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just want the indices. This is faster than the `np.where` method, but still ~1.25x slower than `np.in1d`